# Constructing one concrete boost::tuple type using another

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tuples

Given:

> typedef boost::tuple< T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn > Tuple_Tn

where the types T1, ... Tn are all defined,

And given type T_another, I'd like to define a new tuple type:

> typedef boost::tuple< T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn, T_another > Tuple_T_plus_1

But here is my problem: in the place where I want to define it I only have access to types Tuple_Tn and T_another.

In other words, Is it possible to define Tuple_T_plus_1 in terms of Tuple_Tn and T_another only?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is such a feature in Boost.Tuple, perhaps [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) would be more suited for your needs.

However, if you have a compiler supporting C++11 variadic templates, you can switch to `std::tuple` and write a small metafunction for appending a type to an existing tuple:

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
struct push_back;

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename T, typename... Args>
struct push_back<Container<Args...>, T>
{
    typedef Container<Args..., T> type;
};

typedef std::tuple<int, double> myTuple;
typedef push_back<myTuple, bool>::type myOtherTuple;

myOtherTuple(1, 0.0, true);
```

The same thing can be achieved for `boost::tuple`, but would be much more tedious to write.

Comment: Yep, variadic templates are great. Unfortunately VS 2010 doesn't support it. But thanks anyway :)